# Regex is not matching exact length of string

Tags: regex

I have following regex to validate card number

```
[\d+]{6,6}[X|x]{8,8}[\d+]{4,4}
```

I want to validate following as  valid card number

```
 123456XXXXxxxx1234
```

But anything extra then this should not match.

```
 123456XXXXxxxx1234a
bbb123456XXXXxxxx1234nnn
```

That is these should not match.

I tried this regular expression but it is not working for me.

```
^[\d+]{6,6}[X|x]{8,8}[\d+]{4,4}$
```

Comment: What isn't working with the second rege,?

Comment: Yes . With second regex .  123456XXXXxxxx1234 is coming as invalid

Comment: Are you sure you don't have trailing or leading whitespace?

Comment: Ohh yes. I have. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how to use character classes. Your `[\d+]{4,4}` matches 4 digits or plus symbols. I think you just meant `\d{4}` (4 digits). Right? Also: `[X|x]{8,8}` matches 8 `X`, `x` or `|` symbols. I guess you need just `[Xx]{8}`.

Comment: Yes Thanks. I meant same.

Answer (score 3):

Your `[\d+]{4,4}` matches 4 digits or `+` symbols. I think you just meant `\d{4}` (4 digits). Also, `[X|x]{8,8}` matches 8 `X`, `x` or `|` symbols. I guess you need just `[Xx]{8}`.

I believe you need

```
^\d{6}[Xx]{8}\d{4}$
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/zK3jB4/1)

If you have time, you might want to read more about [*Character Classes or Character Sets*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html).